# Why does composer-patches not work half of the time?

Tags: 8, composer

I am really trying to leverage Composer for workflow and while it is mostly smooth, a big pain point currently is the patch process.

It seems like half of the time, modules are just deleted, and nothing happens.

Here is some recent output.

I added a patch for search_api_solr, and ran composer update for the module:

```
➜ cd ..; composer update drupal/search_api_solr                        
Gathering patches for root package.
Removing package drupal/search_api_solr so that it can be re-installed and re-patched.
Deleting docroot/modules/contrib/search_api_solr - deleted
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)                      
Nothing to install or update
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
```

Uh... it seemed to be aware that there was a patch, but all it did was delete the module and nothing more. I had to follow that with `composer require drupal/search_api_solr:1.x-dev` to get it back.

Other times, I notice when I am just updating a module to its latest version, it will nuke anything listed in the patch list, and not always download them back.

I really don't understand the rhyme or reason here. What is the proper way to ensure this always works?

composer.json:

```
   "extra": {
        "patches": {
            "drupal/better_formats": {
                "Settings have no affect on the field if it is in a Paragraph bundle.": "https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/better_formats_paragraphs-2754029-27.patch"
            },
            "drupal/core": {
                "Improve the Views integration for DateRange fields": "https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/improve_the_views-2786577-129.patch"
            },
            "drupal/image_popup": {
                "Image popup sometimes doesn't work for anonymous users.": "https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/image_popup-attach_dialog_library-2894624-2.patch"
            },
            "drupal/paragraphs": {
                "Removed paragraphs are not unpublished.": "https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/removed-paragraphs-are-not-deleted-2741937-25.patch"
            },
            "drupal/search_api_solr": {
                "Removed paragraphs are not unpublished.": "./patches/comment-missing-files-that-breaks-everyones-tests.patch"
            }
        },
```

Comment: Noticed that too, this isn't a question, it is a bug report.

Comment: Filed one there on GitHub a month ago, no response.

Comment: Also, nothing to do with Drupal.

Comment: This is some crucial info that I wasn't aware about, thx for posting this. A possible alternative/substitute would be to approach this like D7 and use [drush make](http://docs.drush.org/en/7.x/make/) file, assuming they still work on D8 that is.

Comment: @Kevin Can you post relevant lines in your `composer.json` related to the module and patch it-self? Shouldn't you just run `composer update`?

Comment: Wouldn't `composer update` update _everything_? I don't always want to do that.

Comment: Yes `composer update` would indeed update everything. Do you have a link of your GitHub bug report? Interested in following the progress as I am experiencing similar issues.

Comment: https://github.com/cweagans/composer-patches/issues/145

Comment: @NoSssweat drush make/composer work flow will no longer work after 8.4.0 as that functionality is remove from the only version of drush that works with 8.4.x (sadly).

Comment: Does this also happen if you only run `composer install` or `composer update --lock` after adding the patch? You should not need to update the package in order to apply composer patches.